# Incoming webhook not working in rocket chat

Tags: rocket.chat

I created new incoming webhook using rocket chat.

```
> curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data
> '{"username":"Ship Reporter","text":"Example
> message","attachments":[{"title":"Rocket.Chat","title_link":"https://rocket.chat","text":"Rocket.Chat,
> the best open source
> chat","image_url":"https://rocket.chat/images/mockup.png","color":"#764FA5"}]}'
> https://chat.lintcloud.com/hooks/xxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy
```

If i hit the url using curl its give the response false.

```
{"success":false}
```

Anybody know this issue please guide me to fix.